# Randomly selected matrix with no repetition of rows along with its index values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat

I have a 7x10 matrix, from this matrix I want to randomly select 4 rows without any repetition and this selection will include the index values of the selected rows. So, my question is: how to get a randomly selected matrix with no repetition of rows along with its index values of the original matrix  from where it is selected?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
B = A(randperm(size(A,1),4),:)
```

**Update:**  (thanks to federico)

```
idx = randperm(size(A,1),4); 
B = A(idx,:)
```

Now `idx` will be a set of 4 integers between 1 and `n`, where `n` is the number of rows in `A`.

`A(idx,:)` gives you the elements in the rows represented by `idx`.

Comment: But it is not returning the index values of the  main matrix from where the rows are selected.I needed that also along with random selection.

Comment: @shibsankarbhowmick `indexes = randperm(size(A,1),4); B = A(indexes,:)` ?

Comment: But it is not returning the index values of the main matrix from where the rows are selected.I needed that also along with random selection.

Comment: @Federico's solution gives you both! I updated my answer with your solution Federico. I hope that's ok? Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @shibsankarbhowmick yes it does.